# Center and crop thumbnails with CSS keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a thumbnail images but the issue is that when resizing the screen the images leave pink (white) background. How can force images to crop?

Good example of the effect i want is from this website, when looking at developers work thumbnails they resize!: 
http://riccardozanutta.com/

My CodePen:
https://codepen.io/MariusZMM/pen/MZQrVv

```
.project-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.proCont {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 270px;
    width: 420px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #b44dc2;
}

.proCont img {
    position: absolute;

    /* width: 100%;
    height: auto; */

    width: auto;
    height: 100%;

    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* background-position: 50%; */
    /* background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the images 100% wide and tall and use `object-fit: cover`:

```css
.project-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.proCont {
  width: 30%;
  height: 270px;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #b44dc2;
}

.proCont img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-content">
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a class="proCont" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bpnac5F.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: posted same time as you :D

Answer (score 0):

object-fit: cover; did worked i also needed to change width to 100%

https://codepen.io/MariusZMM/pen/gZvvPM

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```